# Annoying game popup

Tags: windows-8, popups

I have a windows 8 PC and my son recently got a free game off the appstore. I don't know how to uninstall it and it keeps sending popups telling me to play the game. How do I end this?

Answer (score 2):

If your son used your personal account, then I would:

1. Backup any save files (if needed/desired)
2. [Deinstall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/uninstall-change-program) the app from your account.
3. Let your son log in using his own account.
4. Let your son install the app using your sons account.

If the game installs some service which raises popups even when you are logged in with a different account then I would just deinstall it and keep it deinstalled (or have your son buy the full version).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to uninstall an app,

Press the Windows key on your keyboard.

Locate the Game on the App Screen.

Right click on the game's tile, and select "Uninstall"

Answer (score 0):

Open your PC control panel by Right-clicking in the screen’s bottom-left corner 
Select Programs and features in control panel menu 
Tap on the game app name, and then click  to Uninstall.
Follow the instructions on the screen.
Install adblockplus in your browser and download any good cloud based antivirus software like [Immunet](http://www.immunet.com/free/index.html) and [Avira](https://www.avira.com) in your windows PC and then perform a complete scan with it